# Calculate maximum value for a measure column without using dimension in mdx query

Tags: ssas, mdx

I would like to calculate maximum value for a measure column without using dimension in mdx query. I tried the following query to achieve this.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Max key] AS
    Max([Internet Sales Amount].Members,[Internet Sales Amount].currentmember.MEMBER_KEY)
SELECT {[Measures].[Max key]} on COLUMNS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

But I got the error in result.

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve my requirement using mdx query?

Comment: Why don't you use a dimension that has a member aggregated to the lowest level? You can check this one https://zahidbi.com/2012/07/27/maximum-value-of-a-measure-from-an-mdx-result-set/

Comment: Thanks. But I dont want repeated values, need to get greatest row value alone independent of any dimension column.Example: MAX(column_name) in SQL server

Comment: yeah but you can use the idea to build your own query

Answer (score 0):

You've written this:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Max key] AS 
    Max
    (
      [Internet Sales Amount].MEMBERS
     ,[Internet Sales Amount].CurrentMember.Member_Key
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Max key]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

`[Internet Sales Amount]` is a measure and therefore a numeric expression so you cannot apply the functions `MEMBERS` or `CurrentMember`. `[Internet Sales Amount]` will not even have keys - so why are you trying to find a max key?

`Max` is defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/max-mdx

You have no choice but to include a set for the max to work over:

> Max( Set_Expression [ , Numeric_Expression ] )

This is a valid use of max:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Max Sales] AS 
    Max
    (
      [Product].[Category].[Category]
     ,[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Product].[Category].[Category] ON ROWS
 ,{
    [Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[Max Sales]
  } ON COLUMNS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It returns this:

[image]